# Issues reading data back from 24LC512 EEPROM via interrupt on MSP430F47187

Tags: i2c, interrupts, eeprom

I have interfaced MSP430F47187 with 24LC512 EEPROM. I am able to write to the EEPROM without any issue but reading the data from the EEPROM is problematic as the reading stops after a while.

I have provided the code below and the screen shot of the data captured on logic analyser.
EEPROM clock is approximately 400K, 3k3 pull-up resistor used on SDA and SCL.

```c
//i2c setup
void initI2C(void)
{
    I2C_PORT_SEL |= SDA_PIN + SCL_PIN;            // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
    // Recommended initialisation steps of I2C module as shown in User Guide:
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSWRST;                           // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTL0 |= UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;        // I2C Master, synchronous mode
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;                         // Use SMCLK, TX mode, keep SW reset
    UCB0BR0 = SCL_CLOCK_DIV;                      // fSCL = SMCLK/10 = ~100kHz
    UCB0BR1 = 0;                                  // keep baudrate high resgiter cleared
    UCB0I2CIE |= UCNACKIE;
    //i2cTxInterruptEN();                         //interrupt enabled
}

//byte write function
I2C_Mode i2cByteWriteIsr(const uint8_t eeprom_i2c_address, volatile uint16_t memAddress, const char *data, volatile uint16_t datasize)
{
    //i2cEnable();                          //enable i2c
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESSHI_MODE;     //set mode to reg mode Hi

    copyData(TXDATA,data, datasize);      //copy data into buffer
    MEMORYADDRESS = memAddress;             //set memory address

    TxByte = datasize;                      //copy size of byte into variable
    RXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceievIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;                      //set index to zero

    slaveAddress(eeprom_i2c_address);       //set slave address
    i2cTxInterruptEN();                     //enable interrupt
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR | UCTXSTT;             //start i2c
    //i2cBusBusy();                           //check Bus is Busy
    __enable_interrupt();                   //enable global interrupt
    return MasterMode;
}

//byte reading function
I2C_Mode i2cByteReadIsr(const uint8_t eeprom_i2c_address, volatile uint16_t memAddress, volatile uint16_t datasize)
{
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESSHI_MODE;     //set mode to reg mode Hi

    MEMORYADDRESS = memAddress;             //set memory address

    TxByte = 0;
    readEEPROM = true;
    RXByteCtr  = datasize;
    TransmitIndex = 0;                      //set index to zero
    ReceievIndex = 0;

    slaveAddress(eeprom_i2c_address);       //set slave address
    i2cTxInterruptEN();                     //enable interrupt
    //i2cBusBusy();                           //check Bus is Busy
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR | UCTXSTT;             //start i2c
    __enable_interrupt();                   //enable global interrupt
    return MasterMode;
}

//interrupt routine
void i2cCallback(void)
{
    if (IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG)
    {
        uint8_t rx_val = UCB0RXBUF;
        if (RXByteCtr)
        {
            RecieveBufferEEPROM[ReceievIndex++] = rx_val;
            RXByteCtr--;
        }
        if (RXByteCtr == 1)
        {
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
        }
        else if (RXByteCtr == 0)
        {
            IE2 &= ~UCB0RXIE;
            IFG2 &= ~(UCB0TXIFG & UCB0RXIFG);
            readEEPROM = false;
            MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
        }
    }
    else if (IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG)
    {
        switch(MasterMode)
        {
            case TX_REG_ADDRESSHI_MODE:
                UCB0TXBUF = (MEMORYADDRESS >> 8) & 0xFF;
                for(int i=1; i>0; i--){}
                MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESSLOW_MODE;
                break;

            case TX_REG_ADDRESSLOW_MODE:
                UCB0TXBUF = (MEMORYADDRESS & 0xFF);
                for(int i=1; i>0; i--){}
                MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESSLOW_MODE;
                if (RXByteCtr)
                {
                    MasterMode = SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE;
                }
                else
                {
                    MasterMode = TX_DATA_MODE;
                }
                break;

            case SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE:
                IFG2 &= ~(UCB0TXIFG);
                IE2 |= UCB0RXIE;
                IE2 &= ~UCB0TXIE;
                for (int i = 1; i > 0; i--){}
                UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
                MasterMode = RX_DATA_MODE;
                UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
                if (RXByteCtr == 1)
                {
                    while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT))
                        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
                }
                break;

            case TX_DATA_MODE:
                if (TxByte)
                {
                    UCB0TXBUF = TXDATA[TransmitIndex++];
                    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--){}
                    TxByte--;
                }
                else
                {
                    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
                    MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
                    IE2 &= ~UCB0TXIE;
                    IFG2 &= ~(UCB0TXIFG & UCB0RXIFG);
                }
                break;

            default:
                __no_operation();
                break;
        }
    }
}


//data logging call from main.c
    if (DataWrite == true)
    {
        i2cByteWriteIsr(I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS, memoryPage, TransmitBuffer,dataLength);
        memoryPage += (dataLength + 1);
        DataWrite = false;
    }
    if(DataRead == true)
    {
        uint16_t tmp = memoryPage;
        i2cByteReadIsr(I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS, (tmp -(dataLength +1)) , dataLength);
        memoryPage += (dataLength + 1);
        DataRead = false;
    }
```

Reading back from EEPROM stops at a random address. In the example below it stopped at address 200. I have seen it stop at different addresses.

```
Restart, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 0, 48, 50, 50, 57, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 0, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 50, 57 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 10, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 10, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 20, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 20, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 30, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 30, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 40, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 40, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 50, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 50, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 60, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 60, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 70, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 70, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 80, 48, 50, 50, 57, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 80, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 50, 57 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 90, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 90, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 100, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 100, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 110, 48, 50, 50, 57, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 110, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 50, 57 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 120, 48, 50, 50, 57, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 120, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 50, 57 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 130, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 130, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 140, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 140, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 150, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 150, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 160, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 160, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 170, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 170, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 180, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 180, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 190, 48, 50, 51, 48, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 190, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48, 50, 51, 48, 48 NAK, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 200, 48, 50, 50, 57, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 200, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48 NAK,
```

Comment: Reading back from EEPROM stops at random address, it stopped at 200 in the example posted above. I have seen stopped at a different adress.

Comment: If you need to add information, please [Edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/666004/edit) your question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: What are the timestamps of those events? You do realize you can't immediately read the memory after a write, as the memory will be busy doing the write internally for up to few millisecond, and it will not acknowledge if you try to access it?

Comment: These devices write slowly; the data sheet specifies 5 mS for a write cycle and we have had to delay 7 mS after a write to guarantee a good read.   Try inserting a delay and see if your problem persists.

Comment: Is the log generated by code, or did you write it manually to demonstrate the communication issue you have?

Comment: Hi Velvel, the data is cpautred on a logic analyser. It showed written data(memory address and sensor data- WR and RD  showed when data are read from a certain memory address).

Comment: @Justme, I have tried adding 5s interval between write and read. The data provided captured on the logic analyser had 5 seconds between write and read.                                                   
 Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 200, 48, 50, 50, 57, Stop
Start, 160 [ 80 | WR ], 0, 200, 
Restart, 161 [ 80 | RD ], 48 NAK,

Comment: @Justme. The data are captured in decimal for the memory address to be readily readable. 4 bytes of data (48,50,50and 57) were written to address 0(High Address), 200(low address).To start reading MCU sent 0 and 200 but only the first byte, one of four was read. I noticed the bus became busy afterwards and MCU command for write and read were ignored. What I don't seem to understand here is why it worked up until address 0,195 and failed at 0,200. BTW I have seen it fail at much lower address like 0,45.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead. Perhaps I should add a delay in between writing to the address to be read and reading from the actual value. Won't a delay in interrupt cause an issue?

Comment: @GBJ OK, having a second look, you start the read OK, read one byte what you wrote, but then there is a NAK on the bus after first byte - that's sent by the MCU so it can't come from the memory chip. Do you have other interrupts running, that might interfere with this interrupt routine, maybe by delaying the execution or interrupting the interrupt?

Comment: @Justme. There are loads of interrupt running ADC, UART, Timer, PWM(Buzzer), RTC etc. I thought that might be the issue, so I disabled  UART because the UART shared the same interrupt vector as the I2C. At times, the buzzer got triggered and required the device to be power cycled to get inhibited when EEPROM behaved as described.

Comment: I usually either poll the interrupt flag in the register, or set a flag in the interrupt service routine and then poll it.  You are right not to do time-consuming tasks in the ISR.  Get in and get out.